# Columns imported to new list from Excel do not appear in default form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, excel-import

I imported an Excel spreadsheet into a Sharepoint list. Only two of the columns actually appeared in the default edit form. The "Edit Columns" option doesn't give me the ability to enable any other columns. If I add a column, it shows up in the form. Edit in Grid View also seems to work.

Is there a way to add these other Excel columns to the form without using PowerApps?

We are on Sharepoint Online, no idea what version.

I tried the "customize form" option with PowerApps, and it seemed to work, but when I went back to SP to test the form, it wanted me to start a trial subscription. I'm assuming that PowerApps isn't something we have as an enterprise.

Comment: How you imported excel file in SharePoint list?

Comment: New > List > From Excel